# Reordering Divs in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set of 4 divs stacked as such:

Div 1

Div 2

Div 3

Div 4

When the browser width is sm or xs, I need to hide the first div and restack the remaining divs:

Div 3

Div 2

Div 4

I already know how to hide the first div, but cannot find a solution for reordering the remaing divs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
TKramer

Answer (score 0):

Because your div's are stacked on all grids and have (as i expected ) `col-xs-12` classes. The `col-xs-12` classes set the width to `100%` and that's why you can't use `float` to reorder your columns (or the push and pull, the .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classes as described at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

A possible solution can be found at: http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/

Using CSS `display:table` you can do:

html:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="div1"> DIV 1 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="div2"> DIV 2 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="div3"> DIV 3 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="div4"> DIV 4 </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
.row {display: table; width: 100%; }
#div1 {display: none;}
#div3 {display: table-footer-group; } /* Will be displayed at the bottom of the pseudo-table */
#div2 {display: table-row-group;    } /* Will be displayed in the middle */
#div4 {display: table-header-group; } /* Will be displayed at the top */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution to have both 1.2.3.4 and 3.2.4 in the DOM, and use the page size to decide which to show.

Comment: I don't have the reputation built yet to upgrade or downgrade this answer, so I just wanted to state that while this may be the simplest solution, it is not the best solution.

Comment: It is the only pure css3 solution. Reordering with javascript is possible.